# Sort a Document by first character

Tags: python

I have amalgamated some files together, what I want to do though is order the output alphabetically according to the first character. I have tried the following but this does not work.

```
filenames = ['1.txt', '2.txt', '3.txt']
with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
             for line in infile:
                 outfile.write(sorted(line))
```

This is the output.txt as it stands:
NH4^       :   0.000 ;  1 ] 2 [ 3
H-         :   0.000 ; -1 ] 4 [ 5
CCL4       :   0.000 ;  0 ] 5 [ 3

Desired output.txt:
CCL4       :   0.000 ;  0 ] 5 [ 3
H-         :   0.000 ; -1 ] 4 [ 5
NH4^       :   0.000 ;  1 ] 2 [ 3

Comment: can you show the line you are sorting???

Comment: The full contents of 1.txt, 2.txt, and 3.txt would help clarify things as well, I think.  Are they each single-line files, or is there more inside?

Comment: Do you really **just** want to sort on the first character in each line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

```
 from operator import itemgetter
    filenames = ['1.txt', '2.txt', '3.txt']
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        total_lines = []

        for fname in filenames:
            with open(fname) as infile:
                total_lines += map(lambda s: s.strip(' '), infile.readlines())

        for line in sorted(total_lines):
            outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: Thanks @Dinesh, I also want to remove any empty space from the beginning of lines in 1,2 and 3.txt. I have the following but it seems I have created an infinite loop; 

    for fname in filenames:
        for line in fname:
            if line.startswith(' '):
                line.lstrip()
                
            total_lines = []
            for fname in filenames:
                with open(fname) as infile:
                    total_lines += infile.readlines()
            for line in sorted(total_lines):
                outfile.write(line)

Comment: @AmyRose Check Edits.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated** to remove leading whitespace before sorting.

Your question is a little open to interpretation, but assuming that you want to sort all lines across a number of files you can simply use [`fileinput.input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input).

```
import fileinput

filenames = ['1.txt', '2.txt', '3.txt']
with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(sorted(line.lstrip() for line in fileinput.input(filenames)))
```

Or, if you want a case-insensitive sort:

```
import fileinput
import string

filenames = ['1.txt', '2.txt', '3.txt']
with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(sorted((line.lstrip() for line in fileinput.input(filenames)), key=string.lower))
```

Comment: Thank you! The lines in 1.txt begin with a space, how would I remove this space from output.txt? I have: if line in filenames startswith(' '):
             line = lstrip(' ')

Comment: @AmyRose - you need to remove the whitespace before sorting as whitespace sorts before alphanumeric characters. Just use `lstrip()` as shown in my updated answer.